# Promise for *ngFor in Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, promise

i'm using angular2 and i'm trying to get the `.style.width` attribute from an element which is loaded inside a `*ngFor`- loop. I want to use it to define the width of some other elements. This should be done while the page loads. I dont want to store the width as some var inside my code. I want to get it directly from the dom.

promise :

```
let kistenPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

            let itemListContainer = document.getElementById("itemContainer");

                if(itemListContainer.children[0] != undefined){
                    resolve(itemListContainer.children);    
                }else{
                    reject(Error("Promise was not fullfilled!"));
                }
}.bind(this));
```

handler:

```
kistenPromise.then(
        function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }.bind(this), function(err){
            console.log(err);
        }.bind(this));
```

html:

```
<div class="itemFrame" id="itemContainer">
        <div class="listStyle" *ngFor="let item of list">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

When i use the colde like this it only returns the `Promise was not fullfilled`.

However if i try `itemList.children != undefined` and return the `.length` it will return 0.What am i missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are getting that error because of some other exception. Can you post some more lines of the error you are getting in the browser console?

Comment: Technically im not getting a real "error" i just get the `console.log` of the `err` i get from the `reject` No other exceptions are comming up. But it makes no sense for me. It gets loaded after 200 ms, i already checked the dom if its really there.

Comment: Object { __zone_symbol__error: Error, fileName: Getter, lineNumber: Getter, columnNumber: Getter, message: Getter, name: Getter, stack: Getter, originalStack: Getter, zoneAwareStack: Getter, toString: value(), 3 more… }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use `AfterViewInit`. Add a local variable `#itemContainer` to your container:

```
<div class="itemFrame" id="itemContainer" #itemContainer>
    <div class="listStyle" *ngFor="let item of list">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

Then in your component you can check the element for children (or pass the element to another function that checks for it):

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('itemContainer') itemContainer: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      if (this.itemContainer.nativeElement.children.length) {
          // ...
      } else {
          // ...
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: This does solve the problem (i already solved this with even load myself) but it does not answer my question why my first solution is not working. Thanks anyways

Comment: Regarding your first solution, maybe you need to wrap your code inside `setTimeout` to make sure it has rendered.

Comment: This was my exact first thought. But this is a very bad use of setTimeout, since slower machines might need longer then the timeout or faster machines could display right away but the timeout holds them back.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what else you can do except try to execute a function when the last item is rendered: `<div *ngFor="let item of list; let last = last;"><span *ngIf="last">{{ yourMethod() }}</span></div>`. But this would execute many times, so you'd have to make sure your function just returns after the first time.

Comment: That would work aswell :) But i think youre missing my point. I want to understand my problem. But i think ill use this workaround now. Thanks for the help Frank

Comment: The problem is that your code executes too early in Angular's component life cycle. So the children in the `*ngFor` have not yet rendered, causing `itemListContainer.children[0] != undefined` to be false, which leads to the promise rejection. I'd like to add that you should probably check `if (itemListContainer.children.length)` instead of `if (itemListContainer.children[0] != undefined)`.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` returns a single element, because id should be unique, and not an array. Other queries do return and array (for example `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementsByTagName`).

Comment: Im sorry, i simplyfied my code so ppl can undstand it and used a missleading variable declaration. What i ment by list was the <div> container which contains the *ngfor elements.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your handler written? It may be getting executed before the view is even initialized. If so, try moving it to `ngAfterViewInit`

**your.component.ts**

```
import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core'
export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        kistenPromise.then(...)

    }
}
```

Comment: Im using this inside the ngOnInit. And i dont want to use something like window.ready or event load... In this case i wouldnt even need a promise.